# How to chain js promises w errors with Parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm in Parse trying to make a beforeSave cloud function for an object "Profile", which is related to User, my goal is to validate that there is no Profile for that User or a Profile with the same user name, the problem is that to verify whether it exists or not, I have to run a query find or get, and fail with code 101 OBJECT_NOT_FOUND, and run in that failure another query and fail, again, to allow the creation of the "Profile" object. 
I do not know how to achieve it.

https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/ that's the documentation and it doesn't explain this case when it's required to continue when there's an error.

```
var beforeSaveProfile = (request) => {
    var profile = request.object;
    var user = request.user;
    profile.id = user.id;

    //check if profile not exist
    const Profile = Parse.Object.extend("Profile");
    const query = new Parse.Query(Profile);
    query.get(user.id).then(() => {
        throw "Profile exists";
    }, (error) => {
        if(error.code === 101){ // ObjectNotFound

            //check if username not exists 
            const query = new Parse.Query(Profile);
            query.equalTo('userName',profile.get('userName'));
            return query.find();
        }else{
            throw "Error: "+error.message;
        }
    }).then(() => {
        throw "Username unavailable";
    }, (error) => {
        if(error.code !== 101){ // ObjectNotFound
            throw "Error: "+error.message;
        }
    });
}
```

I expect that the save is done without error, but it return 101, although I'm wanting that this throw the error messages that see there, when I debugging... the "get(user.id)" works correctly takes the error 101 and runs the query to check the user name, but after this, is going to throw "Username unavailable", when it should go to error 101, because it does not exist

Comment: Yes, when the username `query.find()` succeeds then it's going to throw `"Username unavailable"`, isn't that what you want? When *do* you want to get the "unavailable" error?

Comment: Actually query.find() should return error 101 since it doesn't exist, I also found the solution using .count() instead of .find() or get(), this way I prevent using the method error 101, I also added at the end a .catch((e)=> { throw e;}), later I update this post.

Comment: `.catch((e)=> { throw e;})` is never useful, it behaves exactly the same as if you would omit it.

Comment: So is your question about `query.find()` not doing what you expect, or about your code not handling the result of `query.find()` as you want?

Comment: Ok, then I can omit it, query,find() not  doing what I expect, the query.find() must go to error method, but does not. I guess it's because I execute the query from a method of error... but I replace it with .count() and omit to use error methods